# python - get attribute to subclass

Tags: python, attributes

How to get attribute to subclass? 
I mean the part **age=age**

```
def method(name='thomas', age=27):
   submethod(age=age)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not totally sure what you mean by this code, is the submethod abstract?

Anyway, you're missing `self`, that's not a method. This should work:

```
def method(self, name='Thomas', age=27):
  self.submethod(name, age)
```

If the submethod argument is keyword only, you could rename the local argument value for clarity:

```
def method(self, name='Thomas', age=27):
  the_age = age
  self.submethod(name, age=the_age)
```

Or just don't, keyword names don't collide with local variables anyway, so your original code works once you add the `self`:

```
def method(self, name='Thomas', age=27):
  self.submethod(name, age=age)
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, sorry about that. Thats exactly ehat I mean. So I have to use auxiliary variable?

Comment: er, why? `self.submethod(name=name, age=age)` would work fine.

Comment: @Daniel: I think I considered it a bit confusing to have age = age, but I edited that case in as well, for completeness. Thanks.

Comment: It seems close to telepathy that you managed to asnwer *this* question, +1!